# Show that if $gcd(n,42) = 1$ then $n^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {42} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $gcd(n,42) = 1$ then $n^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {42} $

I notice that $a \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$

In the first case $a=-1,1,-3,3$ In order for the second condition to hold $a=-1,1$ which would imply then that $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$ and $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and $a^6\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ so by the chineese remainder theorem you can conclude that $a^6 \equiv 1\pmod{42}$

Comment: It is not quite clear what you ask, so I just gave the complete proof of the claim. Seems that you have already everything figured out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem gives immediately $n^6\equiv 1\mod 7$

Since $n$ is odd, we have $n^6\equiv 1\mod 2$

Since $n$ is not divisble by $3$, we have $n^6\equiv 1\mod 3$ because of $n^2\equiv 1\mod 3$

The chinese remainder theorem gives $n^6\equiv 1\mod 42$